# Java 8 DateFormatBuilder API to build ISO 8601 Date format

Tags: java-8, date-formatting

I am trying to build a ISO 8601 format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"). Ia m using Java 8 DateFormatBuilder to parse the string in ISO 8601 format.

When I encounter UTC time the output of formatting is "2016-11-01T16:51:35.000Z" but what I really need is have 00:00 instead of Z. I tried DateFormatBuilder to build that but no success.

I finally ended up doing following

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
DATETIMEFOMATTER = builder.parseCaseInsensitive()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
                .toFormatter();

ZonedDateTime zonedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, DATETIMEFOMATTER);
        String utcDate = zonedDate.format(FORMATTER);
        if (utcDate.indexOf("Z") != -1){
            utcDate = utcDate.replace("Z", "-00:00");
        }
```

I do not want to parse the string and replace Z with "00:00". Joda API are easier to work with. Any idea if we can build using Java 8 DateTimeFormatterBuilder? I did refer few stackoverflow questions but didnt work. I may be doing something wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: [`appendPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-)? You wrote the format in the question, I'm not sure what is the issue.

Comment: Thats not working for me.

Comment: Define "not working" please. Post the attempt, and the exceptions / or something else that happened?

Answer (score 11):

## Built-in

Support for the ISO 8601 standard formats for date-time values is built into the java.time classes. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

Your inputs strings can be parsed directly by the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-11-01T16:51:35.000Z" );
```

To generate a similar string with as many fractional second digits as needed in groups of three (0, 3, 6, or 9 digits), simply call `toString()`.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-11-01T16:51:35Z

The `Z` is standard and common to business, aerospace, and military. The `Z` is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

While the `Z` should be perfectly acceptable, you seem to be asking for the offset-from-UTC as a number of zero hours and zero minutes, `+00:00`. While a positive number of zero hours & minutes is also acceptable, **a negative `-00:00` is *not* acceptable** and violates ISO 8601. Your Question’s use of a negative zero offset needs to be replaced with a positive zero.

Note that [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) is supposedly a profile of ISO 8601 yet breaks this rule, allows a negative zero offset, and gives a special and confusing meaning of “offset unknown”. Instead, the sensible way to indicate unknown offset is to simply omit the offset, leaving just the date and the time. This wacky anti-feature is not the only poor design decision in RFC 3339. So I suggest avoiding the RFC and stick with ISO 8601 strictly.

To easily get the string you desire with a positive zero and without bothering with a `DateTimeFormatter` explicitly, use `OffsetDateTime` while assigning a an offset of UTC already defined as a constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`. Then simply call `toString`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
String output = odt.toString();
```

> 2016-11-01T16:51:35+00:00

Comment: I need both of these outputs 2016-10-31T17:10:10.304-04:00 and 2016-11-01T16:51:35.000-00:00 from the same function. I will see if that is possible. I have to have -00:00 as a format as the service that I am consuming needs it in that fashion.

Comment: @Milind Reread my Answer as I warned against using a negative zero. As for needing `-04:00`, I should think the class name `OffsetDateTime` would be a clue. Have you bothered to look at the class doc?

Comment: I will use it and get back to you..Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Basil Bourque Very well expalained